# How to select a particular textbox(with ng-model) in protractor testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

Html Code

```
<li ng-repeat="(i,x) in array">

    {{x.title}} <button ng-click="how(x)">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="x.show" ng-model='x.form'>
        <form name="hola">
            Darsh: <input type='text' ng-model='x.title'>
        </form>
</li>
```

I have binded the input elements with objects, to send info to the backend
I want to do e2e testing for the same.
So I do I select the particular textbox from each element of the array, if I have multiple elements?

Test case in protractor

```
var elem = element.all(by.repeater('(i,x) in array')).get(1);
 elem.element(by.css('button[ng-click="how(x)"]')).click();
 var title = element.all(by.repeater('(i,x) in array')).get(1);
 title.element(by.model('x.title')).clear();
 title.element(by.id('x.title')).sendKeys('how');
```